# ENABLE "run Command as a login shell" in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

I am using vscode on **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**. I have set my **ubuntu's terminal preferences** as **Run command as login shell (bash)**.
Now, i open vs code. It also opens up the integrated bash terminal.
I wanted to know whether "run command as login shell" **is enabled on vscode also?**

Answer (score 15):

I was looking for the same thing today. I think I figured it out as I'm not getting the errors I was before.

I followed the documentation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles

I added a `"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux"` entry in the settings.json file and it auto-added entries for each of the available terminal types. I edited the one for bash to add `"args": ["--login"]` and then opened up a new terminal tab and the new one worked.

Here is the full entry that was added to settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
      "bash": {
        "path": "bash",
        "icon": "terminal-bash",
        "args": ["--login"]
      },
      "zsh": {
        "path": "zsh"
      },
      "fish": {
        "path": "fish"
      },
      "tmux": {
        "path": "tmux",
        "icon": "terminal-tmux"
      },
      "pwsh": {
        "path": "pwsh",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
      }
    }
```

You can run `shopt login_shell` to verify if the terminal is running as a login shell. It will print `login_shell    on` if it is

Comment: this works also with zprofile, setting ["-1"] as mentioned in docs didnt work for me but ["--login"] did on zsh

Comment: Is `shopt` a linux command? VSCode command? I couldn't find it, but supposedly if the result of `echo $0` has a leading `-` then you are in a login shell according to the [LinuxHandbook](https://linuxhandbook.com/login-shell#how-to-know-if-you-are-in-a-login-shell).

Comment: I tried the `bash` part in this answer, and the integrated terminal became a login shell as expected. However, the integrated shell does not provide the `code` command anymore. Is this expected? Is there any elegant way (except exporting `$HOME/.vscode-server/bin/xxxxxxx/bin/remote-cli` to `$PATH`) to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

With Pop!_OS 22.04 and VS Code 1.70 adding this to my user `settings.json` worked:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
      "zsh (login)": {
        "path": "zsh",
        "args": ["-l"]
      }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh (login)"
}
```

This adds a new profile and sets it as the default rather than attempting to override built in profiles.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles